# Downloading an image from AWS S3 using java AWS S3 client sdk and cloudfront CDN end point

Tags: java, sdk, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Currently, I am using the AmazonS3Client instance to download the S3 object using the "key" and "bucket name" as given below.

```
object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(BucketDetails.getBucketDetails(), iconPath));
file  = new File(destinationPath);
reader = new BufferedInputStream( object.getObjectContent());        
writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));  
int read = -1;  
while ( ( read = reader.read() ) != -1 ) 
{     
      writer.write(read); 
}  
writer.flush(); 
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

This by default points to default S3 end point.

I have created a cloudfront distribution for my S3 access.

Can I set the endpoint of AmazonS3Client to cloud front distribution to improve the download performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Cloudfront distribution, and have made the files public, you shouldn't need any sort of AWS client library to access it.  You can just grab the file using your file retrieval mechanism of choice.

Comment: No they are not public. I create the AmazonS3Client using secure tokens and then download the content.

Comment: @user1358538 Then what value do you gain by using Cloudfront?  If you have an EC2 instance in say US-East that is needing to access files on an S3 in the same region, why would you want to go outside the internal Amazon data center to grab the content on an edge node?  It is even worse if you are trying to access a newly created file that has not yet been cached to the edge node you are hitting. In this case, Cloudfront would need to do an origin pull from S3 anyway. If you are working with lots of such files, you might be better served using something like s3fs with cache on local storage.

Comment: How does it differentiate between public and private content? How it works for public static content for a web app. Web application also will be accessed from different regions. What I see the advantage here is, static content can be cached and content will not change frequently. Even same is applicable for me. There will be a lot of content which will remain the same with minimal changes.

Comment: @user1358538 How does s3fs differentiate between private and public content?  I would think the best solution there might to be to keep them in separate S3 buckets and only mount the private files if those are the ones consumed directly by the app, whereas the public static content might actually be best served via Cloudfront.